# How to find the json payload of a specific API in azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I am having issue with an API hosted on Azure APIM. How to find the json payload of a specific API in azure APIM . How to find out the details in logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add Application Insights under Monitoring

[image: Monitoring]

And then you can set on your specific API Diagnostics Logs under Settings

[image: API Diagnostics Logs]

Here you can set what to log and how much

You can see then the payload in Application Insights

[image: Logs]

Comment: Thanks it is helpful

Comment: @RubenSo no problem. Please accept the answer. Thank you